# When an ISP is DDoSed, will its NOC have Internet access?

Tags: ddos, isp, denial-of-service, availability

When an ISP is hit by a huge DDoS attack and its data plane is severely congested, will its Network Operations Center (NOC) have alternative Internet access?

I'm curious what would be the industry practice for the backup, alternative Internet access for NOCs in case of its ISP under attack?

Any thoughts or sharing your experiences would be extremely helpful!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The NOC should have an out-of-band management network to access the devices and apply configuration changes on them. They also should have a separate internet connection so they can search for solutions while the ISP network is having a major outage.

You can watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBO7739TfJE&list=PLbCDrr5wzG7HIl5_93ufK5QEStd0CFP9W&index=13) by Philip Smith on ISP network design which I found very interesting. Philip travels around the world explaining ISPs how to build their networks. Starting at 23:22 he talks about the NOC "module".